# PHP: Current encoding used to send data to the browser

Tags: php, header, character-encoding

How can I know what encoding will be used by PHP when sending data to the browser? I.e. with the Cotent-Type header, for instance: iso-8859-1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually Apache + PHP servers of webhosters are configured to send out **NO `charset` header**.
The shortest way to test how your server is configured are these:

- Use [this tool to see the server header](http://www.seoconsultants.com/tools/headers) by getting any one of your pages on your webiste.
  If in the server headers you see a `charset` it means your server is using it, usually it won't contain a `charset`.
- Another way is to run this simple script on your server: `<?php echo ini_get('default_charset'); ?>` As said above this usually prints out an empty string, if different it will show you the `charset` of the PHP.

The 2nd solution is supposing Apache is not configured with `AddDefaultCharset some_charset` which is not usually the case, but in such case I'm afraid Apache setting might override PHP deafult_charset ini directive.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the header() solution that William suggested, however if you are running Apache, and the Apache config is using a default charset, that will win everytime (Internet Explorer will go crazy) See: [AddDefaultCharset](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#adddefaultcharset)

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that content-types and encodings are two different things.  text/html is a content-type; ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8 are encodings.

The HTTP response header that the server sends typically looks like this:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

"charset" is actually the character encoding.  It's not in a separate header; however there is a header called "Content-Encoding" which actually specifies what kind of compression the response uses (e.g. gzip).

If you want to change the character encoding to UTF-8, in a file that contains HTML:

```
<?
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear: I don't want to set the encoding. I want to know encoding will be set by PHP if I don't set one. I want to know what the default encoding is.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your own with `header('Content-type: xxx/yyy');`, but I believe that text/html is sent by default.

Comment: I don't want to set it, I want to know what default content-type will be set, if I don't set one.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, PHP sends strings bytewise.  that is, if your variables hold UTF-8, it will send UTF-8.  if you have iso-8859-1, it will send that too.  if you mix them, it won't be pretty.

Comment: Right - and I am using the mb_* string conversion function to convert my strings to the "encoding used by PHP by default". But to do the conversion correctly, I need to know the encoding that PHP will be using.

Answer (score 0):

If your server is not configured to have a default content or charset, and neither is PHP, PHP will send only `Content-Type: text/html` - it won't specify a charset at all, and will send the bytes as it sees them in the script.

If a browser receives a page without charset specified, various things can happen:

- most browsers have an "Encoding/Charset" menu; if the user explicitly selects one, the browser will try to apply it. Doesn't happen too often, so:
- some browsers try to render it with a default charset (which is locale-dependent, e.g. for FF and cs_CZ it used to be `iso-8859-2`; YMMV)
- IE will try to determine the charset heuristically (it will take a guess, based on character distribution - and many times it gets it right; sometimes it gets it wrong and you get a page in Romanian interpreted as Chinese text, which usually means "unreadable")
- some old browsers will fall back on `us-ascii`

If with this procedure, the PHP script's charset and the browser's charset matches, the text will - accidentally - be readable. If not, there will be weird signs and similar phenomena.